# Registering a user and signing in with nextauth

Tags: credentials, next-auth, next.js13

I'm a beginner level web developer.

I'm working on a bank website where people can create an account, visit their dashboard etc.
Now, i notice that nextauth can't register a user but can only signIn(Login). I'm using nextauth, provider: CredentialsProvider and Prisma Adapter.

I was able to create a prisma.schema which created a database schema to my mongodb DATABASE_URL.[My Prisma.schema image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE3lO.png) I also created a registration page where new users can register. [my register page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmdor.png) this is my createuser Api [registering a user to User DB collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGIjB.png)

Now adding a user to the User collection works well, but trying to login with the credentials provider is not working[the error i get trying to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wF3w.png) This is my [...nextauth].js [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbRy4.png)

I need assistance

i tried all i can but also nextauth documentation isn't that straightforward and understandable.

What i expect to happen is that, i want to login in with the added user in the user db collection

Comment: please do not use image for showing code

Comment: ok i will correct it